# Is it harmful to block google while I continue to build content?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot

I have been blocking all IPs to my website (except my own) while it is in development.

But now I am at a point, where I want other people to be able to see it, but I still don't want googlebot on it until it is finished.  I just have too many competitors, and I don't want them catching wind of what I'm working on.  Many of them use google alerts.

Is it harmful to block google while I continue to build content?  I would prefer to make it available to Google when it is more developed.  On the other hand, I want to start working on Google+, Facebook, Webmaster tools, and Google analytics now.

Would that cause trouble down the road in the almighty eyes of Google?

Answer (score 1):

> But now I am at a point, where I want other people to be able to see it

Do you mean to show it to others for feedback, review, funding etc? Why not host it on a test server and share the links with them. Hide the site from all bots - no harm here. Use a test domain for this.

As far as I know, facebook etc have some sort of sandbox for testing non-deployed websites.

Google webmaster means you are opening your site to google so it won't work unless you open it to google bot. Analytics is also useless unless you deploy your site for the world to see (including your competitors). I think these 2 things you can add when you are ready for the launch.

Comment: There are some other companies, that I want to begin utilizing the site.  Which is why I don't want it on a test server.  As long as there wouldn't be a penalty from restricting Googlebot for a while (and it sounds like there wouldn't) I will open the site up and just disallow Googlebot until I'm ready.